# How to save the selected items in a listbox?

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-word, word-2003

I have written a simple listbox for a Word form. I wrote this simple code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
     Me.ListBox1.AddItem "ZZ"
     Me.ListBox1.AddItem "yy"
End Sub
```

The listbox works, but I have a problem: because this file is a form, what code I need to write to save the items selected by the user?

Comment: Your code adds these items every time an item in the listbox is clicked. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Where do you want to save it?

Comment: ok. where i need to put this code? thx

Comment: I need to save them in the document (it is a form).

Answer (score 0):

`Me.ListBox1.Value` will return the value selected in a ListBox Control.

Comment: Ok. but how i put this in my doc?
I'm looking on google but i have some problem:
1)I have never written vba code

Comment: @user1474880 I did a search for `put listbox value onto word document` and this was the first result: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=522174

Comment: ok. but how? 
What I need is: I select my item, i save the document and after i re-open my document and I "see" the items that were selected..

Comment: I modified the code: 

Private Sub Document_Open()
     Me.ListBox1.AddItem *******
    End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Comment: @user1474880 Sorry, what do you mean `but how`? The link I gave you shows you exactly how to assign a listbox value to a string variable, then write the string variable's value to the document. I'm afraid I can't make this any easier.